# How to change links in joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla1.5

I am  starter in Joomla and trying to understand this CMS , i just copied 1 Joomla website from one web hosting to another . This is the domain http://tinyurl.com/cmrz9yc
on the top right , it shows images of flags , they're for switching the website language, 
it works fine but the problem is , when i click on the flags , it goes to actual domain , from  where i copied this website . I just want to change the language links to my domain http://jsgarments.net/ . Also when i clicked on the logo , it redirects to actual domain /. I want to change these links to my domain , please help me in this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hi user1124187

    Use ?tp=1 to see the position of the module/component.

    You can use it as mentioned below

    http://jsgarments.net/?tp=1

Login to your admin panel

1. Go to module 
2. Select position top.

you can made changes from there.This part is assigned to position "Top".
or may be you have to do something from template.
```

Hope this will help you.